# NSDictionary init with multiple objects and keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been recently trying to figure out how to init a Dictionary in swift like i used to do in Objective-c:

```
NSMutableDictionary *loginDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[UsernameTextfield.text,PasswordTextfield.text] forKeys:@[@"username",@"password"];
```

i tried to write it in Swift :

```
let userDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: [usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text], forKey: ["username","password"])
```

But i get an error:

> Contextual type AnyObject cannot be used with array literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you have to use the same method, with `objects` and `forKeys` (note the plural).

Then you need to tell the compiler what *type* is each object, in your case it's strings from Optional text labels, so you could do something like this:

```
if let name = usernameTextField.text as? String, let pass = passwordTextField.text as? String {
    let userDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [name, pass], forKeys: ["username", "password"])
}
```

Comment: You can (and should) declare the NSMutableDictionary with `let` because it is a *reference type* ...

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are Passing `Objects` and `Keys` in `NSMutableDictionary` as below, replace your code as below.

```
let userDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text], forKeys: ["username","password"])
```